# python/c++ - incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: python, c++, macos, malloc, lightgbm

So i'm trying this tiny script using LightGBM in python and during prediction it just fails. I get the following error:

`Python(641,0x7fffc8f5c3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc924301078: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Other answers on SO don't seem to be too helpful. This is my first time working with LGBM & python. What can I do to resolve this?

It fails on the predict function provided by LightGBM : 
(`clf` is just some variable which modeled the data)

`p_test = clf.predict(test_data)`

Comment: Did you train the model first?  Pretty hard to say much when you only show one line of code.  Perhaps start with the [Python examples for LightGBM](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/examples/python-guide)

Comment: Hey, thanks. So I changed that line to `p_test = clf.predict(test_data, num_iteration=clf.best_iteration)` which helped :/